# Build Select Dropdown from Knockout Array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of people that i build from an ajax call.

```
var people = GetPeople();

viewModel.people = ko.mapping.fromJS(people);
```

Each viewModel.people contains a first name, last name, email, phone. I'm trying to bind every first name value to a select statement like so:

```
<select data-bind="options: viewModel.people, optionsText: FirstName"></select>
```

It's not working and says FirstName is not defined, which is not true because I use it to create a table and it's fine. What could my error be?

Comment: You have typo in your code - in binding you have "peple" instead of "people".

Comment: oy, thanks for that, in my actual code there isn't a typo

Comment: Also to populate text for each option tag you need to use "optionsText" parameter not "text".

Comment: added, still not working

Comment: Take FirstName property in your binding in quotes like that 'FirstName'.
optionsText: 'FirstName'

Comment: Okay, that works but only provides the first value . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around FirstName property in binding.

```
<select data-bind="options: viewModel.people, optionsText: 'FirstName'"></select>
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCNx5/2/).

Comment: What do you mean "cannot select"? I am able to select "T1".

Comment: Sorry, my browser had a problem. Is there a way to add "Select All" as the first item in the list even though it is not part of the array?

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to select only unique values?

Comment: You can select only distinct values before providing them to ko.mapping.fromJS method.